# Unitary matrix and Spherical Symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra

While reading a paper, I had a doubt with one of the steps followed. Without spoiling anything major, here is my question:

Let 
$$F = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: \|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2 = nP\}$$
where $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^nx_i^2$.
Let $\mathbf{x}_0 = \{\sqrt{P},\sqrt{P},\cdots,\sqrt{P}\}$. Note that $\mathbf{x}_0\in F$. Now let $\mathbf{x}_1$be any other vector in $F$.

Then show that there exists a unitary matrix $Q_{\mathbf{x}_1}$ such that
$$\mathbf{x}_1 = Q_{\mathbf{x}_1}\mathbf{x}_0$$
The idea in the paper is that $F$ has spherical symmetry and so, for the sake of the problem, it suffices to consider only $\mathbf{x}_0$. My reasoning was that if the above lemma is true, then for any other input, I can substitute $Q_{\mathbf{x}_1}\mathbf{x}_0$ and the results should follow.

And this idea works. However I was unable to prove the lemma in the first place. I tried various constructions but nothing seemed to work. So I wanted to know if there is an explicit way to construct the unitary matrices. Even an existence proof would suffice since I don't really need the unitary matrix in an explicit form for every input. Also it does not matter if the matrix is non-unique. One is all i'll need.

Let me know if further clarifications are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(V, \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>)$ be a finite dimensional real inner product vector space and consider the sphere of radius $r > 0$ centered at zero: $F = \{u \in V \, | \, ||u|| = r\}$. Given two vectors $v$ and $w$ in $F$, let us show that there exists an orthogonal map $T \colon V \rightarrow V$ satisfying $T(v) = w$. Since $v,w \in F$, they are non-zero. Complete $v_1 := \frac{v}{||v||}$ to an orthonormal basis $\left( v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n \right)$ of $V$ and $w_1 := \frac{w}{||w||}$ to an orthonormal basis of $(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ of $V$ and let $T$ be the unique linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow V$ satisfying $T(v_i) = w_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Since by construction $T$ sends an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis, $T$ is orthogonal and
$$T(v) = T(||v||v_1) = ||v||T(v_1) = r \cdot w_1 = ||w|| \cdot w_1 = w$$
as required.

If you take $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard inner product, $r = \sqrt{nP}$ then you get the result you ask for.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.